# How Can I Split a Long String Into Lines At "),"?

Tags: java, sql, string, parsing

Having a bit of a headache trying to parse a text file correctly, it's a pull from mysql database but the data needs to be changed a fair bit before it can be inserted again.

My program is taking a .txt file and parsing it to produce a .txt file, which is simple enough.

The issue is that it is not splitting the file correctly. The file looks as follows (the middle field of each looks strange because I've changed it to random letters to hide the real data):

```
(92,'xxxname',4013),(93,'sss-xxx',4047),(94,'xxx-sss',3841),(95,'ssss',2593),(96,'ssss-sss',2587),(97,'Bes-sss',2589),
```

I want to split it so that it produces a file like:

```
(92, 'xxxname',4013),

(93, 'sss-xxx', 4047),

(94, 'xxx-sss', 3841),
```

And so on...

Current code for parsing is as follows:

```
public void parseSQL(File file) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.next();
        String[] lines = line.split(Pattern.quote("),"));

        for (String aLine : lines) {
            logLine(aLine);
        }
    }

}

public static void logLine(String message) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true), 
         true);
    out.println(message);
    out.close();
}
```

Currently the output I'm getting is roughly on track but more split up than it should be, and of course the split method is removing the ")," which is unnecessary.

Sample of the current output:

```
*(1,'Vdddd
Cfffff',1989
(2,'Wdd',3710
(3,'Wfffff
Hffffff
Limited-TLC',3901
(4,'ffffffun88',2714
(5,'ffffff8',1135
(6,'gfgg8*
```

Been playing around for a while and have done a good bit of searching here and elsewhere but out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your input/output blocks by 4, so they are rendered as code with newlines.

Comment: What's wrong with `line.replace("),", ")," + System.lineSeparator())`?

Comment: @ShanuGupta this leads to PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'

Comment: @Michael Where to use that line?

Comment: As an aside, you're going to get rubbish performance from opening a file, appending a line, and closing it. You can reuse the same `PrintWriter`.

Comment: @AndyTurner

yeah I know is just a little program I tried to churn out to save me manually formatting the SQL statements so not really concerned about performance

Comment: Why don't you try to use a regex to get the content between `(` and `),` and convert it into the required file output? Is your text content in the middle expected to have `(` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). There's also no need to create multiple `PrintWriter`s and close the stream every time.

```
public void parseSQL(File file) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true), true);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.next();
        out.println(line.replace("),", ")," + System.lineSeparator()));
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately am still getting breaks where there shouldn't be.

Comment: @EdTaylor Then there are newlines in the input data. i.e. the sample you've provided is not accurate

Comment: (878,'JumpingJackpots - LeeroyGaming', 6656) Gets split into multiple lines...any idea why?

Comment: You could preprocess the input by adding `line.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")` to remove all newlines before splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, this line:

```
String line = scanner.next();
```

Should be:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

Thanks for your attempts folks sorry for being dumb